# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.app.Notification$Builder.addAction

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have developed an android application where i have used notification to be displayed when the application starts

The application works perfect when i run the code on android emulator where as when i try to run the same on real device which has android version of 4.0.4

It throws me error in the logcat as

```
05-13 19:06:45.824: E/AndroidRuntime(15402): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-13 19:06:45.824: E/AndroidRuntime(15402): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.app.Notification$Builder.addAction
05-13 19:06:45.824: E/AndroidRuntime(15402):    at com.example.gpstracker.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:54)
05-13 19:06:45.824: E/AndroidRuntime(15402):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
05-13 19:06:45.824: E/AndroidRuntime(15402):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
05-13 19:06:45.824: E/AndroidRuntime(15402):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
05-13 19:06:45.824: E/AndroidRuntime(15402):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
```

The code which i have tried is ,

```
Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Driver GPS Tracker Application")
                .setContentText("9ciphers")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContentIntent(in)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Start", i)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Stop", in)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Exit", pIntent).build();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // Hide the notification after its selected
        noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Application Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        notifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

can anyone here help me to sort this out am i missing something here

thanks for your help

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`addAction()` was added to API Level 16; Android 4.0.4 runs API Level 15. Either switch to `NotificationCompat.Builder` from the Android Support package, or only call `addAction()` if `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN`.

Comment: but i need different actions to be done on notification panel if i use `NotificationCompact.Builder` it does not add action part in the notification panel

Comment: @NetStarter: "different actions to be done on notification panel" was not supported until Android 4.1.

Comment: @NetStarter http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html.  If your app supports versions of Android as old as API level 4, you can instead use NotificationCompat.Builder, available in the Android Support library

Comment: @Raghunandan thanks i have used the `NotificationCompact.Builder` but it does not have the action part that i was looking for