# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.app.Notification$Builder.build

Tags: android, notifications

I have just added notification icon to the notification bar in my app, which supports Android >= 11 and it started to throw below error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.app.Notification$Builder.build
at com.xynapse.autokam.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:195)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4519)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4464)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:822)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:589)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Below is my part of code responsible for building notification.

```
navigationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
navigationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
navigationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
navigationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, navigationIntent,0);

notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
.setContentIntent(pi)
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.splash_logo)
.setContentTitle("Status")
.setContentText("Standby mode")
.build();
```

Does anyone have any idea why I'm getting NoSuchMethodError for simple .build method? Or am I just missing something here?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
It appeared to me that .build method has been added in API16, stupid question, but maybe it will help someone :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer is just the same as here: [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.app.Notification$Builder.addAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16523807/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-android-app-notificationbuilder-addaction)

You can use `NotificationCompat.Builder` from the Android Support package (`android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder`).