# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError - Notification.Builder

Tags: android, push-notification

I am using version android 4.0.3 but still i am problem with Notification.Builder

In my search i found the notification.builder will start supporting from API level 11+ and android device version 4.x which is API level 14+

so can any one tell me what's the problem with this.

```
notification = new Notification.Builder(this)

.setContentTitle(title).build();
```

Comment: :-post your full code for Notification.Builder and tell me is that you used addAction() for Notification.Builder.

Comment: no i am not using addAction()

Comment: :-Add Android Support package for Notification.Builder.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.app.Notification$Builder.addAction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16523807/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-android-app-notificationbuilder-addaction)